# Gem is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rubygems, gemfile

I have this configuration in my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  # ...
  gem "shoulda-matchers", :git => "git://github.com/watu/shoulda-matchers.git", :branch => "do_not_load_minitest"
end
```

which works fine locally, but when I push to Heroku, when I try to run rake db:migrate, I get this error:

> git://github.com/watu/shoulda-matchers.git (at do_not_load_minitest) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`

Indeed I don't see it in the output of bundle install being run on Heroku, maybe because it's on the test group and Heroku is not installing the test group. But then, why is it complaining when I run rake db:migrate? should it run in staging env?

I tried switching to the http url and all I got is the same error with another URL:

> https://github.com/watu/shoulda-matchers.git (at do_not_load_minitest) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`

Moving the line outside the :test group workarounded the problem. What's the proper solution?

Comment: Run `bundle install` locally, **push Gemfile.lock**, and try again.

Comment: @SamyDindane: I did that to begin with, I always do that when I change the Gemfile.

Comment: what version of rails is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need that gem (since it is in :test group), you can add this configuration to your app:

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" --app <your_app>
```